# What to do when you have more than one column of dependent variable data?

Tags: anova, spss, post-hoc

I ran a 2x2x2 mixed Anova on my data I have only got a significant result for one factor and also a 3-way interaction.

Trying to find out where the significance lies in the 3 way interaction at the min and I have run a million tests and I am not sure which is correct.

Also the other problem I faced with is that my dependent variable is spread over 4 columns in my data file. So my DV is scores on a series of questions but they are spread over 4 columns with different headings `e.g. Speededbio, delayedbio, speededbehavioural, delayedbehavioural`. So when it comes time to put a DV in the correct place for a test I have 4 things?

I know I haven't been all that clear and I'm sure my lack of knowledge and confusion is very apparent any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "dependent variable is spread over 4 columns"? Do you have 4 different DV or is it some kind of software/programming issue?

Comment: Please tell us your real problem, in terms of the application. Wjat question do you want to answer?

Comment: Ok so I was measuring how responses to biological based questions and behavioural based questions differed over 2 conditions. Speeded (respond very quickly) and delayed (wait 10 seconds) so in my data view I have a column of answers for behavioural speeded then a column behavioural delayed and then one for biologically speeded and biologically delayed so my dependent variable is the score on eat of those but because it isn't in one column I can't put it in where you usually put dependent variables.

Comment: So every participant has infor for each of those and then half of participants had a distraction task and the other half didn't. So I found a 3 way interaction with condition, question type and distraction. My problem is I can't figure out how to find where the significant actually lies